# $\mid \partial \phi_u \cdot v\mid\, \leq\, \mid v\mid\,\, \Rightarrow\,\, \mid \phi(u_1)-\phi(u_2) \mid\, \leq\, \mid u_1-u_2\mid $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$-function such that
$$\mid \partial \phi_u \cdot v \mid\, \leq\, \mid v\, \mid$$
for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\partial \phi_u$ is the Jacobian of $\phi$ at $u$. How can I show that $\phi$ doesn't increase lengths,
$$\mid \phi(u_1)-\phi(u_2) \mid\, \leq\, \mid u_1-u_2\, \mid$$

Answer (score 2):

Basically the assumption tells you that all the directional derivatives are bounded by $1$. Then you can apply the multivariable version of the mean value theorem to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: @Mandelbrot the mean-value inequality in higher dimensions says that for any two points $x,y \in \text{domain}(\phi)$, if the entire line segement $x+t (y-x)$, for $t \in [0,1]$, lies inside the domain of $\phi$ then $\lVert \phi(x) - \phi(y)\rVert \leq \left(\sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]}\lVert D\phi_{x+ t(y-x)}\rVert\right) \cdot \lVert x-y \rVert$. In your case, the supremum is $\leq 1$ (it's almost immediate from your given hypothesis).

Comment: Doesn't this only work with real-valued functions?

Comment: @Mandelbrot no, in the form I have stated it (which is an inequality), the theorem holds for any differentiable $\phi$ (you don't even need $C^1$), even if it is a map between Banach spaces (it doesn't even have to be finite-dimensional)

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link for that statement? I have only seen that statement for real-valued function.